# Accessing to an access database in a virtual folder

Tags: windows, tomcat, ucanaccess

I´m developing a web application and i want to manipulate the data of an Access database. 
If I run on Eclipse everything goes perfect with normal(C:\databaseforapp) and virtual folder(created a virtual folder like Y:\databaseforapp), but if I deploy it into a war and run with tomcat... everything goes well if the database is in a "normal" folder, but if It is in a virtual folder doesn´t works(returns a NullPointer Exception when try to connect to the database).

I´m using UcanAccess to manipulate the database.

What can i do?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Try using a UNC path instead of a mapped drive letter. The environment under which Tomcat is running may not have the same (or any) mapped drive letters defined, so "Y:/databaseforapp" could be meaningless in that context, but "//servername/sharename/databaseforapp" might work better.

Comment: Tried and not working, the same exception, working in Eclipse, but not in Tomcat. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Okay, then check the account under which Tomcat is running to see if it is permitted to access network resources. Some built-in security principals such as `LOCAL SERVICE` may be restricted to accessing resources on the local machine only.